# Simplifying integral

Tags: integration, derivatives

There is a problem :

$\int x \ln(x^2)\,dx = \int 2x \ln x\,dx$

How can I simplify the integral like in the right?

I tried to use substitution

$x^2=u$,

$2x=\frac{du}{dx}$

$\int x \ln(x^2)\,dx= \int\frac{u}{2} \ln u\, du$, 
so its not the same?

Can someone point out what is wrong with my attempt?

Comment: The simplest way to compute the given integral is integration by parts.

Comment: @Bernard yes, i feel so stupid :/

Comment: It happens to all of us ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that

$$\ln x^2=2 \ln x$$

note that by substitution $x^2=u \implies 2xdx=du\implies dx=\frac1{2\sqrt u}du$ we obtain

$$\int x \ln(x^2)dx= \int \sqrt u\ln u \frac1{2\sqrt u}du=\frac12\int \ln u \,du$$

Comment: ah using that logarithm property , but is it possible if i use substitution to solve this?

Comment: @vik Yes of course, note that bu substitution we obtain a different integral from the ine you have indicated. It is normal that it is different from the original one. Try to integrate separately and perform the back substitution again.

Comment: $\int x \ln(x^2)dx= \int \sqrt u\ln u \frac1{2\sqrt u}du=\frac12\int \ln u \,du= \frac{1}{2} ulnu-u=\frac{1}{2}r^2ln r^2-r^2$

$\int \ln r^2  r\,du= \int 2lnr r= \frac{r^2lnr}-\frac{1.r^2}{2}$, but why if i use logarithm property, i got different result?

Comment: @vik the first should be$$ \int x \ln(x^2)dx= \int \sqrt u\ln u \frac1{2\sqrt u}du=\frac12\int \ln u \,du= \frac{1}{2} ulnu-u=\frac{1}{2}r^2ln r^2-\frac12r^2$$

Comment: first one, $\frac{1}{2}(r^2ln r^2-r^2 )$ , second one ${r^2lnr}-\frac{r^2}{2}$ right?

Comment: the second $$\int x \ln(x^2)dx=2\int x \ln(x)dx=x^2\ln x-\frac12 x^2$$

Comment: for the first indeed $$...=\frac{1}{2} u\ln u-\frac12 u=\frac{1}{2} x^2\ln x^2-\frac12 x^2= x^2\ln x-\frac12 x^2$$

Comment: oh right, i forgot the log property again, thankyou so much!!!!!!!! :D

Comment: @vik Yes exactly! You are welcome! Bye